# Django - Rest-framework: After Deployment to a remote server wrong results

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

It's a bit frustating:

I had to overwrite the list method in the ModelViewSet, because I need to work with Query Paramters:

```
...
queryset = ABC.objects.all().filter(Y = 1, X = 1)

self.object_list = self.filter_queryset(queryset)
page = self.paginate_queryset(self.object_list)
if page is not None:
        serializer = self.get_pagination_serializer(page)
else:
     serializer = self.get_serializer(self.object_list, many=True)
return Response(serializer.data)
```

Locally it works fine. But after the deployment to a remote server I dont get any results using the same URL. I dont think, that this is a CORS-issue, but after hours of searching I absolutely cannot find the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually with problems in a different environment the issue is in the different URL's. For instance your url's might not be resolving because of the different host prefix etc.

At least my problems similar to it have always been the result of url conf.